How to populate adaptive card table row from array parameter
I'm trying to use json response send to microsoft teams channel using adaptive card but i'm having problem to use the array data to generate the table row.
This is the result that i'm trying to achieve. Design using adaptivecards designer

For workflow, refer below

For the output for Parse JSON, refer below
{
  "took": 129,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 9,
    "successful": 9,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 10000,
      "relation": "gte"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "query": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 62,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 105204,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "method 1",
          "doc_count": 2583767
        },
        {
          "key": "method 2",
          "doc_count": 2094948
        },
        {
          "key": "method 3",
          "doc_count": 723921
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

For Adaptive Card format, refer below
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "text": "Weekly Summary Report"
        },
        {
            "$data": "${body.aggregations.query.buckets}",
            "type": "Table",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "width": 3
                },
                {
                    "width": 1
                },
                {
                    "width": 1
                }
            ],
            "rows": [
                {
                    "type": "TableRow",
                    "cells": [
                        {
                            "type": "TableCell",
                            "items": [
                            {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "${key}",
                            "weight": "Bolder"
                            } ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TableCell",
                            "items": [
                            {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "${doc_count}",
                            "weight": "Bolder" 
                            } ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TableCell"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.5"
}

My question is how to access aggregations > query > buckets and dynamically render the table row for key & doc_count?
In adaptive designer i can access the data by assigning to $data property "$data": "${body.aggregations.query.buckets}".
Any help is appreciated.

Could you please try this updated JSON and let us know if it helps?

{ "type": "AdaptiveCard", "body": [ { "type": "TextBlock", "size": "Medium", "weight": "Bolder", "text": "Weekly Summary Report" }, { "type": "Table", "columns": [ { "width": 3 }, { "width": 1 }, { "width": 1 } ], "rows": [ { "type": "TableRow", "cells": [ { "type": "TableCell", "items": [ { "type": "TextBlock", "text": "Method", "weight": "Bolder" } ] }, { "type": "TableCell", "items": [ { "type": "TextBlock", "text": "Doc Count", "weight": "Bolder" } ] }, { "type": "TableCell" } ] },

{ "$data": "${aggregations.query.buckets}", "type": "TableRow", "cells": [ { "type": "TableCell", "items": [ { "type": "TextBlock", "text": "${key}" } ] }, { "type": "TableCell", "items": [ { "type": "TextBlock", "text": "${doc_count}" } ] }, { "type": "TableCell" } ] } ] } ], "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json", "version": "1.5" }
